# makefile pattern rules without recipes

Tags: makefile, rules

I'm observing an interesting behavior of make and I wonder if there is a reasonable explanation to it besides a bug in gmake.

Let's say we have the following in makefile:

```
%-animal:
        echo "$* is an animal"

%-fox: %-fox-animal

%-wolf: %-wolf-animal
```

The difference between the last two targets is that "%-wolf" does not have any recipe, and "%-fox" has an empty recipe (i.e. just a line with a tab at the beginning).

When we try to execute the rules, here's what happens:

```
[root@cv19 tmp]# make freddy-animal
echo "freddy is an animal"
freddy is an animal
[root@cv19 tmp]# make freddy-wolf
make: *** No rule to make target `freddy-wolf'.  Stop.
[root@cv19 tmp]# make freddy-fox
echo "freddy-fox is an animal"
freddy-fox is an animal
```

i.e.the pattern rule that has a recipe (although an empty one) works, the one that doesn't  does not. Am I missing something in the way it's supposed to work?

Comment: What you call 'recipe', make calls 'rule to make'.  So its message agrees with what you think it should do: there is a rule for freddy-wolf, but no rule '*to make* freddy-wolf.

Comment: @reinierpost: The GNU Make 3.82 release included an epic documentation search/replace creating the term 'recipe' for the set of commands used to update a rule's target.  So (1) it's not just m1tk4's term and (2) this was a surprise to me too.  See r1.51 of http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/make/doc/make.texi?root=make&view=log

Comment: @John Marshall: hmmm ... good to know, thank you.  (I'm on 3.81 until Cygwin will update it.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pattern rules with no recipes at all are documented as meaning something quite different from those providing a recipe, even an empty one.  Instead they [cancel any pre-existing implicit rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html):

> You can cancel a built-in implicit rule by defining a pattern rule with the same target and prerequisites, but no recipe.

Thus your "%-wolf" pattern actually serves to cancel any existing implicit rule for *%-wolf-animal* -> *%-wolf*.  And there wasn't one anyway.

Comment: How does one get the desired effects of pattern prerequisite-only rule?

Comment: I hate make, and this kind of thing is why. It's full of nonsensical, exception-based rules. Why would `target: pre-reqs` work one way but `pattern-target: pre-reqs` another?!