# Make rule without recipe but with prerequisites?

Tags: makefile

Is it possible to create a `Makefile` that has a catch-all rule (i.e. `%: ...`) with prerequisites but no body?

Here is an example of the problem I'm having:

```make
.SUFFIXES:

%: patches/% downloads/%

patches/%:
    @echo $@

downloads/%: patches/%
    @echo $@
```

```
$ make patches/latest
patches/latest
$ make downloads/latest
downloads/latest
$ make latest
make: *** No rule to make target `latest'.  Stop.
```

I can "solve" this issue by adding a body to the catch-all rule:

```make
.SUFFIXES:

%: patches/% downloads/%
    @echo $@

patches/%:
    @echo $@

downloads/%: patches/%
    @echo $@
```

```
$ make patches/latest
patches/latest
$ make downloads/latest
downloads/latest
$ make latest
patches/latest
downloads/latest
latest
```

Is it possible to do this without having a recipe for the catch-all rule?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728689/makefile-pattern-rules-without-recipes) but it was never really answered properly (i.e. a possible solution).

Answer (score 4):

As the linked question points out, pattern rules with no recipes [cancel pre-existing rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

Give the rule an empty body:

```
%: patches/% downloads/% ;
```