# Makefile: how to declare a dependency for all targets that match a pattern?

Tags: makefile

Certain files in my target have dependencies on other targets. I can ensure a proper build by adding explicit rules like this:

```
static/app.mjs: js2/.legacy_app.built.mjs
static/admin_unit.mjs: js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_source.mjs: js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_module.mjs: js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
```

But this means changing my Makefile every time I add a new "admin_X" source to my project. What I would like to do is have a catch-all pattern rule like:

```
static/app.mjs: js2/.legacy_app.built.mjs
static/admin_%.mjs: js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
```

But this does not work, as explained by https://stackoverflow.com/a/3734705/179583:

> Pattern rules with no recipes at all are documented as meaning something quite different [… :] they cancel any pre-existing implicit rule

Is there a clean way to specify that "any target matching a certain pattern" depends on some particular other target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, a pattern rule like:

```
static/admin_%.mjs: js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
    recipe...
```

does not specify any targets, just a template for discovering
the prerequisites of targets that you specify *otherwise*,
with a recipe for making those targets from the prerequisites.

So there has to be something *else* in your makefile that determines
what the targets are. Let's suppose it is just a list as in:

```
$ cat Makefile
MJS_STEMS := app admin_unit admin_source admin_module
MJS_FILES := $(addprefix static/,$(MJS_STEMS:%=%.mjs))

.PHONY: all clean
all: $(MJS_FILES)

$(MJS_FILES): js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs

static/%.mjs: | static
    @echo $< > $@
    @echo "$@ depends on $<"

js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs: | js2
    touch $@

static js2:
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(MJS_FILES) js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
```

Here,

```
$(MJS_FILES): js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
```

says that each of `$(MJS_FILES)` depends on `js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs`.
That's the most concise way to do it without a pattern rule. The make runs like:

```
$ make
mkdir -p static
mkdir -p js2
touch js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/app.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_unit.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_source.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_module.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
```

If you want you can move the maintenance of the `MJS_STEMS` list out of the
makefile into another file:

```
$ cat ./mjs_stems
app
admin_unit
admin_source
admin_module

$ cat Makefile
MJS_STEMS := $(shell cat ./mjs_stems)
MJS_FILES := $(addprefix static/,$(MJS_STEMS:%=%.mjs))

.PHONY: all clean
all: $(MJS_FILES)

$(MJS_FILES): js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs

static/%.mjs: | static
    @echo $< > $@
    @echo "$@ depends on $<"

js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs: | js2
    touch $@

static js2:
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(MJS_FILES) js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs


$ make clean
rm -f static/app.mjs static/admin_unit.mjs static/admin_source.mjs static/admin_module.mjs js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs

$ echo "admin_foobar" >> mjs_stems
$ make
touch js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/app.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_unit.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_source.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_module.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_foobar.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
```

Or you can just get the `MJS_STEMS` list from the environment:

```
$ cat Makefile
MJS_STEMS := $(strip $(MJS_STEMS))
MJS_FILES := $(addprefix static/,$(MJS_STEMS:%=%.mjs))

.PHONY: all clean
all: $(MJS_FILES)

$(MJS_FILES): js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs

static/%.mjs: | static
    @echo $< > $@
    @echo "$@ depends on $<"

js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs: | js2
    touch $@

static js2:
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(MJS_FILES) js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs


$ make clean
rm -f static/app.mjs static/admin_unit.mjs static/admin_source.mjs static/admin_module.mjs static/admin_foobar.mjs js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs

$ export MJS_STEMS=$(cat ./mjs_stems)
$ make
touch js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/app.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_unit.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_source.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_module.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/admin_foobar.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs

$ make clean
rm -f static/app.mjs static/admin_unit.mjs static/admin_source.mjs static/admin_module.mjs static/admin_foobar.mjs js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs

$ export MJS_STEMS="aa bb cc"
$ make
touch js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/aa.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/bb.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
static/cc.mjs depends on js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs

$ make clean
rm -f static/aa.mjs static/bb.mjs static/cc.mjs js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
```

But one way or another, somewhere, you have to specify the list of targets, and
to add new targets you have to update something.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't think it directly answers my question but if not that's partly my fault for leaving out some of the background: I do already generate a list of target files via `appfiles = $(shell ls -1 js2/*.build.mjs)` and `js2: $(appfiles:js2/%.build.mjs=static/%.mjs)` [I forget if there was a reason for splitting it beyond readability.] So in this case I'm only trying to cleanly "call out" some of them as having an extra dependency. As @Matt reminds below, I should be able to use similar `ls -1`/substitution tricks to generate a sub-list.

Answer (score 1):

If all those files already exist in the filesystem (i.e. not supposed to be built by make from scratch), you can use `$(wildcard ...)`:

```
$(wildcard static/admin_*.mjs): js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my case the `static/admin_*.mjs` targets are some of the final products of this Makefile, and won't always be present e.g. after my `make clean`.

Comment: Ah, but as @MikeKinghan brings up in his answer — I can figure out what files *should* exist based on a different wildcard pattern (e.g. `src/admin_*.build.mjs`) so I can probably combine this with a substitution.

Answer (score 0):

I found another trick to do this, under the special case that all relevant files are built via their own particular recipe. I.e. this will **not** work in the general case, unless you have split out or can duplicate a separate recipe for the targets in question.

Granting that, it's a simple matter of tying in the common dependency via a phony target. This `ADMIN` target depends on the shared intermediate file, and then in turn is specified as a prequisite of a pattern-matching recipe:

```
.PHONY: ADMIN
ADMIN: js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs

static/admin_%.mjs static/admin_%.mjs.map: js2/admin_%.build.mjs ADMIN FORCE
    node_modules/.bin/rollup --config rollup.config.js $< --format esm --sourcemap -o $@

# …also contains recipe to build "js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs" itself
```

Now before *any* `static/admin_%.mjs` file is built, make ensures that the common `js2/.legacy_admin.built.mjs` helper file has been created.

(See [when multiple pattern rules match a target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455182/when-multiple-pattern-rules-match-a-target) for some background on how various versions of Make pick which recipe to use.)